# Mysql incorrect calculating

Tags: mysql, database

i fixd last issue, but now have lil bit other: i was edt my query in this format. But, i still have 1 big problem - PU_1day & PU_7day calculating incorrect: additional "1" in each line (3 when true is 2, and 1 when true is 0). How i can fix this? :(

```
SELECT u.date, 
       u.des_channel, 
       u.des_type, 
       u.country,
       count(distinct(u.id)) as Reg_n, 
       sum(if((u.date=bp.date)*(u.id=bp.user_id),bp.o_outcome,0)) as P_$,
       sum(if((u.date=bp.date)*(u.id=bp.user_id),1,0)) as P_n,
       count(distinct(if((u.date=bp.date)*(u.id=bp.user_id),bp.user_id,0))) as PU_1day,
       count(distinct(if(truncate(timestampdiff(hour,u.datetime,bp.datetime)/24,0)<7,bp.user_id,0))) as PU_7day
FROM mayadata.users u 
left join mayadata.billing_pays bp
       on u.id=bp.user_id
WHERE  u.country in ('TH','ZA','ID','IN','NG','MY') and
       truncate(timestampdiff(hour,u.datetime,bp.datetime)/24,0)<7 and 
       u.date>='2011-01-01' 
GROUP BY u.date, u.des_channel, u.des_type
```

Comment: Subtract one from the calculation? I mean... it's going to count that '0' value as one distinct. You might also experiment with switching your `0` with `NULL` and see if that helps. I can't recall if MySQL counts `NULL` as a distinct value. I know in other RDBMSs that NULL is not considered into `DISTINCT` counts.

Comment: As per JNevill... COUNT() will not include NULLs.  You could COUNT(IF(whatever, 1, NULL)) ...

Comment: Oh, thx guys, sounds pretty right, hope its works!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing the second parameter to **null** from **0** in the PU_1day & PU_7day calculation expression like below:

```
SELECT u.date, 
       u.des_channel, 
       u.des_type, 
       u.country,
       count(distinct(u.id)) as Reg_n, 
       sum(if((u.date=bp.date)*(u.id=bp.user_id),bp.o_outcome,0)) as P_$,
       sum(if((u.date=bp.date)*(u.id=bp.user_id),1,0)) as P_n,
       count(distinct(if((u.date=bp.date)*(u.id=bp.user_id),bp.user_id,null))) as PU_1day,
       count(distinct(if(truncate(timestampdiff(hour,u.datetime,bp.datetime)/24,0)<7,bp.user_id,null))) as PU_7day
FROM mayadata.users u 
left join mayadata.billing_pays bp
       on u.id=bp.user_id
WHERE  u.country in ('TH','ZA','ID','IN','NG','MY') and
       truncate(timestampdiff(hour,u.datetime,bp.datetime)/24,0)<7 and 
       u.date>='2011-01-01' 
GROUP BY u.date, u.des_channel, u.des_type
```